# Jquery find within an array of elements

Tags: jquery

I have selected a bunch of li elements that meet a certain criteria like so:

```
var x = $('li[attribute="value"]');
```

Now rather than searching the dom again, I want to search x for an li tag that has a specific id. I could use a .each to search x but was wondering if there was a one line statement I could use.

something like this:

```
var myLi = x.find("[id=23]");
```

or is it faster to search the dom using the id tag. What if I wanted to search on a second attribute?

Please advise.

Thanks!

## Edit

Please note that I want to change the properties of myLi (say make its background color red) so I need a ref to the element. thanks.

Comment: if you provide fiddle, then it's easy to solve your problem

Comment: I'd say, go the easy way first (searching the DOM for the ID) and see if it has any impact. Do some profiling if you want to. If you search for another attribute, then yes, filtering the current list is better.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do so:

```
var myLi = x.filter('#23');
```

> **jquery.filter():** Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match
>   the selector or pass the function's
>   test.

Answer (score 1):

The following are the various ways in which you can get the element starting from the fastest

[**Profiled result**](http://jsfiddle.net/jishnuap/ZjWb6/1/)

1. [The ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)
2. [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
3. [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)